# Run large php scripts without them timing out?

Tags: php

I'm trying to mass compress images with GD on my site, it works just fine when I try to compress a small folder with 20 images but I have around 70k images and when I use the script I get a timeout and 500 error message. This is the code:

```
$di  = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./image/data/');
$iter  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di);
$regexIter = new RegexIterator(
$iter, '/^.+\.jpg$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

foreach ($regexIter as $fileInfo) {
  $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($fileInfo[0]);  
  imagejpeg($img,$fileInfo[0],

 75);
}
```

Now I already searched for this topic and found out that I can use:

```
set_time_limit();
```

So I decided to add

```
set_time_limit(100000);
```

but this is not working, I still the timeout message and no images are compressed

Do you have any suggestions on how I could do this efficiently because typing in every folder would take me weeks.

Comment: Is this timing out as a CGI script? If so, do you have the means to run it as CLI?

Comment: Did you try `set_time_limit(0)`? - If limit is set to 0, no time limit is imposed.

Answer (score -1):

the better way to do big works is to do these in more parts.

e.g. you move the treated pictures in another directory and you stop the script after 100 pictures.
then you just have to restart the same script a few times and all pictures are done

Comment: And still better would be to use a simple job scheduler and process the images in background.

Comment: The problem is that the images are in hundreds of subfolders so I can't just put the images in a new folder because I need them in the specific subfolders.

Comment: another solution is to log the name of the pictures already optimized

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question, increasing the timeout is something you should ask your hosting provider. Of course, they may refuse to do it.

A good idea is to transform your script to run from command line. The processing is faster and the timeout is usually much, much higher. But then again, it requires for you to have command line access on the server.

Last and preferred option is to transform your script into "chaining". Since most of the time will be spent doing the actual image conversion, this is what I would do:

- get a list of all images with their full path; save in session or in a temporary table
- start processing each image from the list, deleting it after it's been done
- at every image, you check how much time it's passed since the start of the script, and if it's getting close to the timeout, you redirect to the same script with an additional "offset" parameter